# What can we conclude from "f is not little-o of g"?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Given two functions $f$ and $g$, what does "$f$ is not $o(g)$" mean ? What can we conclude from this statement ?

I know "$f$ is $o(g)$" means the limit at infinity of $\frac fg$ is zero.

So does "$f$ is not $o(g)$" mean the limit at infinity of $\frac fg$ is different from zero or does it mean that this limit doesn't exist ?

Comment: Both cases are possible.

Comment: It means that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that given any $N$ there is an $x>N$ with $f(x)/g(x)>\epsilon$. This statement says nothing about whether there is a limit at infinity.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, I believe that you need an absolute value around $f(x)/g(x)$, but otherwise spot on.

Comment: @Tom, Ah, yes, there was no assumption that the functions are positive. (So $f(x)/g(x)>\epsilon$ should have been $|f(x)/g(x)|>\epsilon$ in my previous comment.)

Comment: @Andres Maybe you should make your comment into an answer

Comment: @TrevorWilson Sure, done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f = o(g)$ does mean that the $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$. Notice that saying $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$ is actually the statement "the limit of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists as $x \to \infty$ AND the limit is $0$". The negation of this, "$f$ is not $o(g)$", means that we negate the previous statement resulting in "the limit does not exist OR if it does exist, it is not $0$."

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear answer.

Comment: This answer is a good explanation, but it's not quite precise because the second clause "the limit is zero" after the "AND" presumes that the limit exists.  Its meaning can't really be separated from the first clause.

Comment: @TrevorWilson, I don't quite agree that it's not precise. If $A$ and $B$ are propositions such that $B \implies A$ and I say "$A$ AND $B$" and negate this as "(NOT $A$) OR (NOT $B$)" was I imprecise? I do agree that implicitly in the statement that the limit is zero, that we are assuming it exists, but it is still a logically correct statement.

Comment: If you just treat "the limit is 0" as a propositional variable $B$, then certainly your logic is correct. However, the "(NOT $A$) OR (NOT $B$)" you would end up with would say "the limit does not exist OR it is not the case that the limit is 0", which is different than what you said.  Perhaps my point should be that the second disjunct "it is not the case that the limit is zero" is the only one you need, and figuring out what exactly this means is in a way equivalent to the question itself.

Comment: @TrevorWilson I agree. My above comment isn't in exact analogy with what I wrote above; you make a good point! To be clear for readers, if $A$ is "the limit exists" and $B$ is "the limit is zero" then the question asks to clarify "NOT $B$". To help with clarity, I said read $B$ as "$A$ AND $B$" (even though this is really just $B$), and negate it as "(NOT $A$) OR ($A$ AND (NOT $B$))" (even though this is really the same as NOT $B$).

Answer (score 1):

That $f$ is not $o(g)$ simply means that there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $N$ there is an $x>N$ for which $|f(x)|>\epsilon|g(x)|$.

Note that this formulation does not require $g$ to be nonzero for $x$ large enough. If the set of $x$ where $g(x)$ is zero is unbounded, clearly $f(x)/g(x)$ does not converge as $x\to  \infty$, since there is an unbuonded set of points where the fraction is undefined.

But even if $g(x)\ne 0$ for $x$ large, the formulation in the first paragraph is not strong enough to allow us to conclude anything about whether the limit exists. For a silly example, if $g(x)=2$ for all $x$, and $f(x)=2$ for $x$ an integer, but $f(x)=0$ otherwise, then $f$ is not little-oh of $g$, but the limit does not exist (in this case, we can take $\epsilon=1$). On the other hand, if $g(x)=2$ for all $x$, and $f(x)=4$, then the limit exists.

By the way, the big-oh notation is due to Bachmann (around 1894), and later adopted by Landau (to whom many attribute it), and it was already common in the early twentieth century. On the other hand, the little-oh notation, due to Landau (around 1909) took a bit longer to be adopted. For example, Hardy's book [**Orders of infinity**](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/38079) uses the $O$ notation, but does not use $o$, and uses $\epsilon$ instead of $o(1)$, as in 
 $$ n!(e/n)^n=(1+\epsilon)\sqrt{2\pi n}. $$